# Share one of the main linux directories on server for all network clients

Tags: networking, server, administration

I'm trying to setup a network that I share `/usr` folder on my server and use it for all my clients so I don't need to update my `/usr/lib` for all clients every time and just updating server for all the network.

Just give me a clue, I have no idea how to Google it!

#### Edit:

sorry i'm beginner

I want my network just to have one source of repository, i mean for example, when i downloaded python3 on the server, all the clients can use it so i don't need to download python3 for all of clients one by one

Comment: Sorry? Explain what is user specific content in /usr/lib/ that needs updating for specific users?  Oh and you do not mess with permissions in system related directories.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but unsupported. The performance will be mediocre, due to added latency and throughput limit. In short, export /usr via nfs on the server, and mount it at all the clients.

Comment: @vidarlo so its obsoleted and not recommended?!

Comment: Obsolete... disk speeds has run away from network speeds, especially with SSD's. It works, but it introduces new problems. You may for instance want to have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto - the main difference is that you'd boot a minimal system from disk, and mount /usr/ and possibly others via NFS.